# First try on string array not working. Is there something I don't know?

Tags: c++

I just tried to use string array for the first time, and I experienced consistent crashes. It's supposed to draw a shrinking circle. Did I forget to add some important line, or is there an error in the existing code? I'm a beginner, so please don't be too mean..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int h = -10; h < 10; h ++)
    {
        int r = abs(h);
        string gps[20];
        for (int i = -10; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = -10; j < 10; j ++)
            {
                if (i*i + j*j <= r*r && i*i + j*j >= (r-1)*(r-1))
                    gps [j+10][i+10] = char (219);
                else
                    gps [j+10][i+10] = ' ';
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j ++)
            cout << gps[i][j];
        cout << '\n';
    }
    //system("CLS"); // I know this isn't the best method, but it's the only one i know that works
    // By proffesional analysis (cout), i diagnosed the problem to occur right about here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each of your 20 stings is empty, you cannot use `[]` on empty string.

Comment: Not to mention that, quite often, `j` is 0 or positive, so setting `gps [j+10]` to anything will not end well.

Comment: You wrote code to use string arrays, but you are totally forgetting the fundamentals of how to access the string elements safely.  You cannot access elements in a string that do not exist.  `string s; s[4] = 'x';`  That will fail because the string has no 5th element that can be changed.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thx, 'string gps[20][20]' works

Comment: @warduck -- It does not "work".  You are accessing an element out-of-bounds, meaning that you are invoking undefined behavior.  This is the danger of using arrays -- you can access elements out-of-bounds, and you have no warning that the code is faulty, all because the undefined behavior is one where it looks like the code is working.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It does work and there is no out-of-bounds access. `std::string` has assignment operator for `CharT` for some reason, and that would be used there. But I'm not sure if OP is aware that `string gps[20][20]` means a 2D array of 400 strings.

Comment: `gps [20]` -- Means that there are 20 empty strings.  Accessing the nth element of an empty string such as `gps [j+10][i+10] = ' ';` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I assumed you were replying to the comment "Thx, 'string gps[20][20]' works". With this change code will work. Sorry if I misinterpreted.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, looking at the code posted, it is no wonder it crashes.

Comment: *"Is there something I don't know?"* -- yes, I am rather sure there are a good number of things you do not know. Just like there are for most people. You might find that answers are more likely to be helpful if you refrain from spurious, open-ended questions and instead focus on a specific issue. You might find it helpful to write out an explanation of why each and every line of your code is unquestionably correct. The full explanation does not need to go in your question; the process of writing it out can help clarify to yourself what the real, specific question is.

Answer (score 1):

One major issue with your code is that you are writing to the string at an out-of-bounds index here:

```
 //...
 gps [j+10][i+10] = char (219);
 //...
 gps [j+10][i+10] = ' ';
```

This declaration:

```
string gps[20];
```

declares an array of 20 **empty** strings.  Since the strings are empty, you cannot simply write to any position in these string.  These strings must already be sized appropriately before writing to a particular location.

What you may need to do is the following:

```
string gps[20];
for (auto& s : gps)
  s.resize(20);
```

This will resize each string in the array to 20 elements, thus making your loop access valid entries in any of those strings.  Writing to an out-of-bounds string position is undefined behavior, where in your case, the program crashes.

Now, will this draw the circle correctly, I am not sure.  But this answer focuses on the crash you are getting when running the program.